# How to get a property of HTML into typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I have a `<mat-paginator>` in *.component.html whose properties are defined as below:

```
 <mat-paginator #paginator
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
  (page)="onPaginateChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

Is it possible to get the property `pageSize` into my *.component.ts?

Tried referencing the native html element, but no use

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the `mat-paginator` via `@ViewChild` decorator and try to access it in the `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle event hook.

```
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.paginator.pageSize)
}
```

Also when looking [**documentation**](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api) it gives you `pageSize` in the `page` event

> PageEvent Change event object that is emitted when the user selects a
>   different page size or navigates to another page.
>
> pageSize: number - The current page size

Comment: @Do we really need ViewChild? why can't we use 2 way binding? Also PageEvent already contains all the info

Comment: Where to use two-way binding ?

Comment: I mean instead of hardcoding page size to 10, she can declare typescript variable and bind

Comment: I agree with you. But `mat-paginator` does not give a two way binding as I know, so changing size during application run, we can get it only in the event handler or using template reference

Comment: yea, I remember. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

you can access pageSize using ViewChild

here's an example

```
export class PaginatorOverviewExample {

  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.paginator.pageSize)
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8x4qb6?file=app%2Fpaginator-overview-example.html) demo